# PHP | DOMDocument - get JSON data from body

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, domdocument

What i am trying to do is get the document title from body using DOMDocument

e-g    "document_title":"iOS Programming Nuts and bolts",

The result of this code is that I get a null value on $doc_name variable.. I want the result to be `"iOS Programming Nuts and bolts"`

**Edit :** I'm trying to get json data from html source (e.g : document_description , document_title etc..)

Source code:

[image: Please check this image]

this is so far i have

Please help friends..

```
<?php 

$doc_url = "https://www.scribd.com/book/281016724/iOS-Programming-Nuts-and-bolts";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$doc_url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($http=="200") {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars($result));
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $js = $xpath->query('//body/script[@type="text/javascript"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $start = strpos($js, '{');
  $end = strrpos($js, '),');
  $json = substr($js, $start, $end - $start);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  $doc_name = $data["document_title"];
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately you haven't identified a specific problem, any errors or what does and what doesn't work as outlined in [ask]. That makes it very difficult for anyone to know what you need specific help with

Comment: Not clear whether you are attempting to get json or a html page.  The url you have specified is a html page.  If you are attempting to get the title of the html page you could use php string functions (you have some strrpos() and substr()) to parse the document but why you are then json decoding it is unclear.  What page and page type are you retrieving?

Comment: There are multiple `<script type="text/javascript">` but you're just blindly grabbing `->item(0)` and assuming it's the right one.

Comment: Honestly you could probably just regexp the whole document for `/"document_title":"(.*?)"/` with maybe some added fanciness to allow for escaped quoted in the title.

Comment: @Rahul Rajeev try a code xpath ``//h1[@class="document_title"]`` ... xpath dont work find scripts (javascript), just html or xml.